# Leaflet Contextmenu - How to pass a marker reference when executing a callback function (non-geoJSON marker)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, contextmenu

I am having troubles with executing callback functions on markers (in my case they are circle and semiCircle markers). The marker context menu extends map's context menu with additional marker-specific operations. Map context menu callbacks are working properly. Marker additional menu options are shown, but I cannot execute the corresponding functions (for example getting Lat and Lon of a marker). The error in both variants that I tried (see below) is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLatLng' of undefined".

Below is shown the code that I am using.

Markers are created from external JS file and stored in a layerGroup.

**Variant 1** - Using event "contextmenu.show" as suggested in contextMenu documentation.

Creating layerGroups with Circle markers:

```
for(i in sites) {
var title = sites[i].ID,    
    loc = sites[i].loc,     
    object = sites[i].Type,
    marker = new L.circle(new L.latLng(loc), {radius: radsiteinit+50,color: 'gold', weight: 3, title: title, pane: "sitePane",
           contextmenu: true,contextmenuItems: [{text: 'Show Charts',index:0}, {separator: true, index: 1}]} ).
           bindPopup(object+': '+ title ).on('click', onClick);

    layerSites.addLayer(marker);
}
```

"contextmenu.show" event:

```
    mymap.on('contextmenu.show', function (event) {

    var latlngs = event.relatedTarget.getLatLng();

});
```

As mentioned above produced error is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getLatLng' of undefined". Also event is fired before user gets the chance to select and option from context menu. What I need is to fire the event after user selects some marker-specific options from context menu.

**Variant 2** - With definition of callback function.

Creating layerGroups with Circle markers - the difference here from above is that I added callback function is context menu definition:

```
for(i in sites) {
var title = sites[i].ID,    
    loc = sites[i].loc,     
    object = sites[i].Type,
    marker = new L.circle(new L.latLng(loc), {radius: radsiteinit+50,color: 'gold', weight: 3, title: title, pane: "sitePane",
           contextmenu: true,contextmenuItems: [{text: 'Show Charts',callback:showCharts,index:0}, {separator: true, index: 1}]} ).
           bindPopup(object+': '+ title ).on('click', onClick);

    layerSites.addLayer(marker);
}
```

Callback function definition:

```
function showCharts(e) {

    var latlngs = e.relatedTarget.getLatLng();

};
```

The same error here.

I am very new to JavaScript, so I guess I do something wrong when I am trying to pass marker's reference to the function (var. 2) or event (var. 1).

Because I am stuck a lot, I would appreciate getting some advice.

Thank you in advance!

**EDIT**
In the link you can find a JS Bin example of variant 2:
[JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/fewusak/edit?js,console,output)

Comment: Could you possibly provide a JSBin or JSFiddle with the minimum amount of code required to reproduce the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
var circle = L.circle(new L.LatLng(-36.79, 174.7), {
  radius: 400,
  weight: 10,
  contextmenu: true,
  contextmenuItems: [{
    text: 'Circle 1',
    callback: function() {
      showCharts(circle);
    }
  }]
}).addTo(map);


function showCharts(circle) {
  console.log(circle.getLatLng().toString());
}
```

Key points:

- Declare a variable and assign your circle marker to it (`var circle = L.circle(...)`).
- Set the `callback` property to an anonymous function. Within that function, execute your`showCharts` method and pass it the `circle` variable as an argument (`showCharts(circle)`).

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/paratak/7/edit?js,console,output) with a working example.

#### Update

For multiple circle markers, you can do something like this:

```
for (var i in sites) {
  var title = sites[i].Site,
    loc = sites[i].loc,
    marker = new L.circle(new L.latLng(loc), {
      radius: 100,
      contextmenu: true
    }).bindPopup('Site: ' + title);

  marker.options.contextmenuItems = [{
    text: 'Show Charts',
    callback: (function(marker) {
      return function() {
        showCharts(marker)
      }
    })(marker)
  }]

  layerSites.addLayer(marker);
}
```

The code makes use of closures to keep track of the correct marker variable within the loop.

Test it out in [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/ticakoz/5/edit?js,console,output).

Comment: Thanks, Iavor! Your example works. But it is different than what I am aiming. In my case I am loading thousands of markers in several Layer Groups, so I do not keep separate variables for each one of them. In the Edit of my post I put a JS Bin example as you suggested (I am using it for first time and this is a great service :)

Comment: Yeah, JSBin is very useful  Check out the update in my answer. Let me know if helps.

Comment: Amazing! It works like charm. You made my day :) I am sure that your working solution will benefit also other people.

Comment: Awesome! I'm glad it works and that I made your day. Good luck with your project Ivaylo!  